# How to make python accept strings as unicode in python2.7

Tags: python-2.7

I wrote a web scraping code in python 3.6 and the text part is Unicode in it. my boss asked me to use python 2.7 instead for existing codebase compatibility.

I changed basic things like formatted print and division etc... I am getting the same output for python 2.7 also, but if I see the string processing 
it's showing in this way with Unicode prefix

```
u'10. Can a customer get a welcome kit containing ATM card, chequebook, and internet password at the time of opening the account?'
```

> just to be in the safe side for future issues I want to make python
>   2.7 treat strings as python 3.6, is it possible?

Comment: are you irritated by `u` prefix?

Comment: want to know if just ```u``` prefix is the change or there may be some more unknown issues